# Merge and display 2 database and 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys i have a problem, there is a page where i need to display data acording to date, but from 2 databases and from 2 tables from each databases,

1 Database name = highmob_comenzi Tables = players and vanzari 
 
2 Database name = highmob_comenzi2 Tables = players and vanzari

this is the code what i got , i have tryed "select * from players, vanzari" but still no luck, even that wont extract data from both databases :(

```
<table class='table table-responsive-sm table-bordered table-striped table-    sm' border="2px">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Locatia Vanzari</th>
<th>Tip. Cert.</th>
<th>Nr.</th>
<th>Status Comanda Mobila</th>
<th>Status Comanda Tapiterii</th>
<th>Status Livrare</th>
<th>Ora Livrare</th>
<th>Detalii Comanda</th>
<th>Total</th>
<th>Avans</th>
<th>Rest</th>
<th></th>
</tr>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id";
$password = "pw";
$dbname = "highmob_comenzi2";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = ("select *
 from highmob_comenzi.players 
 cross join highmob_comenzi.vanzari
 union all 
 select *
 from highmob_comenzi2.players 
 cross join highmob_comenzi2.vanzari
  WHERE statuslivrare >= CURRENT_DATE()");
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "


</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>

<td>HERE DATABASE NAME</td>
<td><a href='vezibilettransportcomenzi.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'     target='_blank'  class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>Tip. Cert.</a></td>
<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>
<td>
" . $row["statuscomanda"] . "
</td>
<td>" . $row["statuscomandatapiterii"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["statuslivrare"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["oralivrare"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["detaliicomanda"] . "</td>

<td>
 " . $row["totaldeplata"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["avans"] . " <br><a style='color:red;'>" . $row["banipreluati"]     . "</a></td>
<td>" . $row["restdeplata"] . "<br><a style='color:red;'>" .     $row["banipreluatirest"] . "</a></td>
<td><a href='edit.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'  target='_blank' class='btn     btn-sm btn-primary' >Vezi comanda</a></td>
</tr>





    ";
    }
} else {
echo "Nu sunt transporturi!";
}

$conn->close();
?> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: probably a join in the select, but not enough information to know for sure

Comment: lets join for the momment only 2 tables :) table players and table vanzari any ideea how to do it? i tried allready "select * from players, vanzari" but not working!

Comment: need table schema, sample data, sample desired output

Comment: Well i try to display data from 2 tables

Comment: i have edited the post to see what i have now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access to the table  in the same query without problem  eg (assuming the tables have the same struct in both the database):

```
 select *
 from highmob_comenzi.players 
 cross join highmob_comenzi.vanzari
 union all 
 select *
 from highmob_comenzi2.players 
 cross join highmob_comenzi2.vanzari
```

this is only a sample for accessing to the 2 database in a single query. you must  rethink the query with you join and condition

but based on you comment seem you need  just (assuming that statuslivrare  is  a colum of the vanzari table)

```
 select *
 from highmob_comenzi.players 
 cross join highmob_comenzi.vanzari
 WHERE vanzari.statuslivrare >= CURDATE()");
```

Comment: i have edited the post but still not working :( check now

Comment: it would be good if i manage to display data from 1 database but 2 tables then i can try to do it from 2 databases!

Comment: if the 2 database are on the same server there are not problem  my answer use 2 database and 2 table from each database  ..

Comment: yes, both databases are on the same server but its still not working :(

Comment: you have errror ?  ... show the exact error message .... and remember that my  sql code is just a sample  ..

Comment: there is no error its just says that there are no data to display!

Comment: try var_dump($result) and check the real content ..  but this seems another question to  mme

Comment: im getting the else echo "nu sunt transporturi"

Comment: with var_dump im getting "comenzi2.highmob.ro is currently unable to handle this request"

Comment: try var_dump($result)  .. otherwise your tables are empty  ..  (or you have some others error somewhere)

Comment: comenzi2.highmob.ro    seems not  the database name you have in your code .. explai better  .

Comment: yes, comenzi2.highmob.ro its the website , but the databases are like this: highmob_comenzi2 and highmob_comenzi with tables players and vanzari

Comment: . are you sure for the correct name???  the 2 couple of tables area exactly the same  ..  ??? try instead of select * select a single (same) column from both  the select in union

Comment: im 100% sure , there are 2 website's 1 is comenzi.highmob.ro that use database highmob_comenzi and have tables players and vanzari (tables that i need to display) and the second website is comenzi2.highmob.ro that have database name highmob_comenzi2 and i need also to display tables players and vanzari

Comment: are you sure you are connected  to the  database ?..  and you have the grant for accessing  on to both the database and table?  and last  are the two database mysql  database?  and try using explicit column name instead of *  (just for test try a single column)

Comment: well i think using this: $servername = "localhost";
$username = "id";
$password = "pw";
$dbname = "highmob_comenzi2";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); i have access only to one database?

Comment: can you show me how to display data from 1 database but from 2 tables? tables players and vanzari?

Comment: no  ... the connection establish a connection with the mysql dbserver .. once you have a connection you can select form all the database  table you need  pefixing the tablename with the database name  ..

Comment: if you want only a db and both the table you can use  `select *  from highmob_comenzi.players   cross join highmob_comenzi.vanzari`

Comment: ohh God i got no ideea how to establish connection with 2 databases, i think if you could help me just with 1 database but with those 2 tables players and vanzari it would be ok :)

Comment: for get the data for a single database just remove the 2nd select after the union all  clause

Comment: that seems to work but now i need to have the "where" clause .. WHERE statuslivrare >= CURRENT_DATE()

Comment: also with select * from highmob_comenzi2.players cross join highmob_comenzi2.vanzari im getting alot of duplicate's

Comment: build the query you need ... as i tell you before my code was only a sample  .. i don't know your db data content and what you want to retrive effectively ... this is not related  to your original question ..    .. ..

Comment: check my other answear i have posted the code there you can see what im trying to get

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "ID";
 $password = "PW";
 $dbname1 = "highmob_comenzi2";


 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname1 );
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 $sql = ("select * from highmob_comenzi2.players cross join      highmob_comenzi2.vanzari
   ");
      $result = $conn->query($sql);


 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "


 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>

 <td>HERE DATABASE NAME</td>
 <td><a href='vezibilettransportcomenzi.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'      target='_blank'  class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>Tip. Cert.</a></td>
 <td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>
 <td>
 " . $row["statuscomanda"] . "
 </td>
 <td>" . $row["statuscomandatapiterii"] . "</td>
 <td>" . $row["statuslivrare"] . "</td>
 <td>" . $row["oralivrare"] . "</td>
 <td>" . $row["detaliicomanda"] . "</td>

 <td>
  " . $row["totaldeplata"] . "</td>
 <td>" . $row["avans"] . " <br><a style='color:red;'>" .      $row["banipreluati"] . "</a></td>
 <td>" . $row["restdeplata"] . "<br><a style='color:red;'>" .      $row["banipreluatirest"] . "</a></td>
 <td><a href='edit.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'  target='_blank' class='btn      btn-sm btn-primary' >Vezi comanda</a></td>
 </tr>





        ";
     }
 } else {
     echo "Nu sunt transporturi!";
 }

 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

This is what i got and its working, it displays data from 1 database nammed highmob_comenzi2 and tables players and vanzari, but im getting alot of duplicates on display and also i need to insert a WHERE clause :

WHERE statuslivrare >= CURRENT_DATE()

any ideea?